# Find the maximum volume of the cylinder.

Tags: geometry, derivatives, supremum-and-infimum

A cylinder is obtained by revolving a rectangle about the $x-$axis,the base of the rectangle lying on the $x-$axis and the entire rectangle lying in the region between the curve $y=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ and the $x-$axis.Find the maximum volume of the cylinder.

I could not solve this problem,i could not understand clearly the problem,how a rectangle can lie between $y=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ and the $x-$axis and how to find the max volume.Please help me.

Comment: Go to wolfram alpha and search for y=x/(x^2+1). You'll see it is a plotted as a curve that initially goes up and then heads asympotically to 0. You can draw various size rectangles in that space. Each rectangle can be revolved to form a cylinder. The question is what's the biggest such cylinder.

Comment: Take a look at the curve. It reaches a maximum value at x = 1/2 and then slowly bends towards the x axis, ultimately touching it at infinity. Once you can picture this, then drawing a rectangle and setting up the necessary equations will not be difficult.

Comment: After you have the picture, draw a horizontal line at height $y$, where $y$ is fairly small, say $0.2$. This line meets the curve at two points $A$ and $B$. The cylinder has radius $y$ and length $AB$, so volume $\pi y^2(AB)$. Find $AB$ in terms of $y$, and maximize. To find $A$ and $B$ you will need to solve $x/(1+x^2)=y$ for $x$. This is the quadratic $yx^2-x+y=0$.

Comment: **Hint:** Given what you already wrote, it is clear that the cylinder of maximum volume corresponds to the rectangle of maximum area.